# Display Waveform from PCM File or FFT

Tags: ios, audio

I need a way to create a waveform graphic from a PCM or FFT File, similar to how Apple's sample code "aurioTouch", displays a waveform from input (a microphone).

I have tried implementing the classes and methods from aurioTouch, but the application is incredibly confusing for me.

I need to be able to read the frequencies of the audio file, which was an m4a, and now is PCM encoded; I can use FFT as well. How should I go about reading the frequencies of the audio file?

Comment: Unclear question.  Are you asking how to plot a graph of the data from your FFT?  Or are you having problems reading some audio file?

Comment: Right now, the file is in PCM format, I need to plot a graph of the frequencies. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You may look for aurioTouch 2 which is using the vDSP API after ios4 to do the calculation.
Ref for fft function in vDSP API could found in [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/vDSPExamples/Listings/oneDimFFT_c.html).

I guess following aurioTouch 2 could get what you want. (at least I get similar thing by it(

For reading file from any supported audio format, you could read [mixer host](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MixerHost/Introduction/Intro.html).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To display the frequencies you will need to perform a spectral estimation. FFT simple converts time information into frequency information. I am assume what you want to do is is show frequency changes over time. What this involves is chopping the audio file into overlapping blocks applying an envelope to the blocks (fade in and then fade out) and then perform FFT on each block. I just did a quick search for 'spectral estimation core audio' and there are some promising looking stuff in apples core audio you should look into

[The Sonogram View Demo Audio Unit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2200/_index.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Should I have the audio file in PCM, before I convert it to FFT?  If I had more rep, I would 1-up your answer :/

Comment: Yes, FFT usually work with though internally they translate that into complex numbers. You do not need the whole sound file though just enough to fill one block to pass to the FFT.